# Is it possible to change the uninstall icon in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

From what i've read it looks like that is no parameter that allows you to change the uninstall icon:

```
[Setup]: UninstallIconFile
Description:
Obsolete in 5.0.0. As Setup and Uninstall have been merged into a single executable, setting a custom icon for Uninstall is no longer possible.
```

So, is there another way to change this icon? 
I'm asking because if, for example you have only your launch exe, an readme and the uninstall, users may accidentally click on the uninstall instead of lauch, which is a little bit annoying.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Uninstall Icon would only be the same as your application icon if you set the `IconFilename` setting to the same icon as the application or have the `SetupIconFile` setting set to the same as your application.
By default, the Uninstall Icon is the same as the Setup icon.  If you really want to make sure the user isn't confused, you can set the `IconFilename` parameter in the `[Icons]` section to your uninstall icon.  Something like:

```
Name: "{group}\Uninstall My Program"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; IconFilename: "{app}\uninstall.ico"
```

You would need to include the uninstall.ico in your `[Files]` section as well.

Answer (score 12):

To change the uninstall executable icon, you have to change the installer executable icon, as it is the same exe, using the [`SetupIconFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_setupiconfile) setup section directive.

For example:

```
SetupIconFile=MyProgSetup.ico
```

You can also change the Icon that is displayed on the control panel, setting the [`UninstallDisplayIcon`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstalldisplayicon) setup section directive

For example:

```
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe,4
;or
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\Uninstaller.ico
```

Answer (score 2):

The "setup.exe" file icon can be set by `SetupIconFile`

The control panel icon can be set by `UninstallDiaplayIcon`

In script file, I added these lines to the `[Setup]` section:

```
[Setup]
    .
    .
    .
; Icons for setup.exe and control panel
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\Icon.ico
SetupIconFile="Icon.ico"
```

Note that:

1. `UninstallDisplayIcon` is given `{app}` path
2. `SetupIconFile` uses absolute path, because the setup program to be created by Inno (by compiling) is yet to have `{app}` before my program is installed.

jachguate's answer has given me the best clue to figure out my case. This solution is tested on a few Windows 10 computers.

Answer (score 2):

In Win10 This works for me when you need to have the same icon as the application icon:

```
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\youApp.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the uninstaller icon as `SetupIconFile`, then change the resource icon in the compiled *.exe*. (There are many programs to do that like the [ResHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/))

If you see the compiled *.exe* still with the uninstaller icon, just move that *.exe* to another folder and you will notice.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Icon that is displayed on the "Control Panel -> Uninstall or Change a program" and "Settings -> Apps & Features" by adding following into your inno script under `[Setup]`

```
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
```

The above sets the [UninstallDisplayIcon](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstalldisplayicon) for the setup which is displayed in Settings.
Enter the name of your exe file instead of "MyProg.exe".

For additional information,The [SetupIconFile](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_setupiconfile) attribute takes icon file as value, and it is used to display icon for Application's shortcut, Windows Start window.

```
SetupIconFile=ApplicationIconFileName.ico
```