# Unistall icon default of inno setup

Tags: icons, inno-setup, uninstallation

I am using Inno Setup (5.5.3) to create an executable. i wish to use the default uninstall icon (ex: the same uninstall icon of My Program inno setup example). When i create my executable, the uninstall icon of my program is the same icon of the program, and this can generate confusion for the users.

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "Remove xyz-duplicate LiDAR points"
#define MyAppVersion "0.2 Beta"
#define MyAppExeName "remove_duplicate_xyz_executable_project.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{73F937B9-0CD9-44F1-B07E-17CD2399EE13}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
AllowNoIcons=yes
OutputBaseFilename=Remove xyz-duplicate LiDAR points
SetupIconFile=C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\iconRemoveduplicate_two_80res_small.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "brazilianportuguese"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\BrazilianPortuguese.isl"
Name: "danish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Danish.isl"
Name: "french"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\French.isl"
Name: "german"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"
Name: "italian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Italian.isl"
Name: "norwegian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Norwegian.isl"
Name: "russian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Russian.isl"
Name: "spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\_ctypes.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\_hashlib.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\_socket.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\_ssl.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\bz2.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\library.zip"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\python27.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\remove_duplicate_xyz_executable_project.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\select.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\unicodedata.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the uninstall icon in Inno Setup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170456/is-it-possible-to-change-the-uninstall-icon-in-inno-setup)

Comment: Hey Deanna i flag to delete this question

Comment: definite duplicate of [using inno setup uninstall default icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845226/using-inno-setup-uninstall-default-icon)

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the icon you want to appear in the menu adding a IconFilename parameter to your icon entry, like this:

```
[icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}" IconFileName: "{app}\MyUninstallerIcon.ico
```

More info in the [help](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection)

> **IconFilename**
>
> The filename of a custom icon (located on the user's system) to be displayed. This can be an executable image (.exe, .dll) containing icons or a .ico file. If this parameter is not specified or is blank, Windows will use the file's default icon. This parameter can include constan

Comment: what error message? and well, try also the IconIndex parameter. If it helps I'll change my answer to that. ;)

Comment: The answer's code is just an example, in real life you have to include the hypotetical MyUninstallerIncon.ico file in your `[files]` section! (You notice that reading the manual ;))

Comment: Come on, don't be harsh with me, remember that I'm trying to help you!