# using inno setup uninstall default icon

Tags: icons, inno-setup, uninstallation

I am using Inno setup adding an uninstall icon to Start Menu Foulder.

using the Inno Setup Script Wizard (example My program), there is a default uninstall icon[image]

this is the code of example.

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{9BBC9685-FB4E-4BF1-B2B4-07A46B467911}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
AllowNoIcons=yes
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{#MyAppURL}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

I wish to use the same Uninstall default icon inside my software in order to avoid to download icon from internet or create an my own icon.

the code of my inno setup software is the following. Using this code the Uninstall icon is the same icon of .exe.

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "Remove xyz-duplicate LiDAR points"
#define MyAppVersion "0.2 Beta"
#define MyAppExeName "remove_duplicate_xyz_executable_project.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{73F937B9-0CD9-44F1-B07E-17CD2399EE13}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
AllowNoIcons=yes
OutputBaseFilename=Remove xyz-duplicate LiDAR points
SetupIconFile=C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\iconRemoveduplicate_two_80res_small.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "brazilianportuguese"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\BrazilianPortuguese.isl"
Name: "danish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Danish.isl"
Name: "french"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\French.isl"
Name: "german"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"
Name: "italian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Italian.isl"
Name: "norwegian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Norwegian.isl"
Name: "russian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Russian.isl"
Name: "spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\_ctypes.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\_hashlib.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\_socket.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\_ssl.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\bz2.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\library.zip"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\python27.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\remove_duplicate_xyz_executable_project.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\select.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\dist\unicodedata.pyd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: It's because you use Icon for Setup File `SetupIconFile=C:\PythonScript\Script_fun\Remove_duplicate_xyz\LiDAR_Remove_xyz_Duplicate_Point_executable_project\iconRemoveduplicate_two_80res_small.ico`. If you want to have generic icon, you should use generic for both Setup and Uninstall, or if you specify icon for Setup, you should specify icon for Uninstall as well with `UninstallDisplayIcon=`.

Comment: Thanks RobeN. I am really beginner in Inno steup and it's not clear how resolve this. I wish to use a icon "iconRemoveduplicate_two_80res_small.ico" for the setup and the default icon for the uninstall. Is it a problem to ask you the correct code line? thanks in advance

Comment: @RobeN but if i specify an icon for Uninstall  with UninstallDisplayIcon, do i need to have a file *.ico?

Comment: Yes, Icon lub Exe with icon inside. If you set icon for Setup it is inherited by Uninstall by default unless you specify different icon for Uninstall.

Comment: @RobeN and why with the inno setup default example (MyAppName "My Program") i have an uninstall icon without setting an icon *.ico file? See example above

Comment: Because there is also no `SetupIconFile=` specified so both Setup Exe and Uninstall Exe have Default icons like on your picture.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27691/discussion-between-gianni-and-roben)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the uninstall icon in Inno Setup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170456/is-it-possible-to-change-the-uninstall-icon-in-inno-setup)

Comment: @Deanna no i don't think so

Comment: @Gianni I do. It explains how to set the uninstall icon which seems to be what you're asking. If you want to use the same one from the sample script, then do so, just copy it from the location the sample script uses.

Comment: @Deanna i fixed just using ResourcesExtract. Using  ResourcesExtract i extracted the file *.ico that i wish. Otherwise i didn't find a working code in inno setup. I am curious to test your approach if you publish a code

Comment: @Gianni My approach? I use the code from the answer I linked to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27706/discussion-between-gianni-and-deanna)

Comment: @Deanna, OK I will continue to use the file ico extract by ResourcesExtract. It's the elegant way from my point of view. Thanks for help/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you set `SetupIconFile` then the Uninstall Exe File (e.g. unins000.exe) will have exactly same icon implemented. One way to override displaying of this icon is setting custom `UninstallDisplayIcon` in `[Setup]` section for Control Panel Add/Remove list and `IconFileName` in `[Icons]` section for shortcuts placed on Desktop, Start Menu, etc. In both cases you have to have your custom Icon file which has to be installed with your app.

```
[Setup]
SetupIconFile=C:\mysourcedir\mysetup.ico
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\myuninstall.ico 
                        //overrides icon on Add/Remove List in Control Panel

[Files]
Source: "C:\mysourcedir\myuninstall.ico"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}";
 IconFilename: "{app}\myuninstall.ico" 
                       //overrides icon in Start Menu shortcut
```

The second one is to have precompiled unins000.exe with specific icon implemented. It can be tricky though in some cases (multiple install with unins001, unins002, etc.; custom code features)